# How can I modify the server date so that it lines up with the date of my users (8 hours ahead)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have this SQL that creates a group by date report:

```
select [Date] = convert(date, a.Date)
    , [Count] = count(*)
from Audit a
group by a.Date
```

The problem is that the SQL Server date is 8 hours behind the date when the users are entering data.

Is there a way that I can change the date that is being used for the group by so that it groups by the correct date for the user time zone (8 hours ahead)

So for this:

```
2017-03-01 1:45
2017-03-01 8:45
2017-03-01 8:45
2017-03-01 8:47
2017-03-01 8:45
```

Before - not correct

```
2017-03-01 5
```

After - what I need

```
2017-03-01 1
2017-03-01 4
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the date  is after 8 AM it should be new row or you want to group by each hour ?

Comment: Create a view that does what you need, but generally you should be storing all your dates in UTC.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try dateadd function to add 8 hours in the query.

select [Date] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, a.date), 101)
    , [Count] = count(*)
from Audit a
group by CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(HOUR, 8, a.date), 101)

Comment: Can you give me an example on how I could fit this into the SQL Query in the question. Thanks

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, 8, '2017-03-01 08:00');

Comment: Hi,  I saw a lot of downvotes.  You need to give an example as I think people are not happy with just one line answers.  Can you give an example of how to modify the query question and I think then it would be okay. Thanks

Comment: I thought dateadd clue would be enough for developers anyways, here is the query probably it will help.

Comment: select [Date] = DATEADD(HOUR, 8, a.date)
    , [Count] = count(*)
from Audit a
group by DATEADD(HOUR, 8, a.date)

Comment: Thanks but there is still a problem as each date needs to be a whole date.  What I get is this:2017-02-19 20:07:51.110 1
2017-02-19 20:10:56.037 1
2017-02-19 20:11:47.287 1
2017-02-19 20:12:39.583 1
2017-02-19 20:12:52.380 1
2017-02-19 20:13:47.527 1
2017-02-19 20:20:03.557 1

Also can you add this to the answer.  One line answers like you have will almost always be downvoted a lot.  Thanks